# Heterogeneous running times when mapping over parallel sequence in Scala

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

When mapping over a parallel sequence, it seems that Scala assigns a fixed CPU core to each planned computation element, and then prevents this initial assignment from changing.

```
List(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l).par.map(someComputation)

// (Simplified) initial assignment for a 2-cores machine:
// Core 1: a, b, c, d, e, f
// Core 2: g, h, i, j, k, l
```

The problem is, if `(a .. f)` are very fast and `(g .. l)` take 1 hour each, we're gonna end up with Core 1 sitting idle for 6 hours while Core 2 is trying to get its work done.

Is there a way to do parallel computation such that *if Core X is free and there are unstarted jobs left, feed Core X with one of these jobs*?

**EDIT**

To reproduce, fire up a Scala REPL and type in:

```
scala> :paste

def compute(x: Int) = {
  if (x > 10)
    (0 to 10e9.toInt).foreach(n => n + 1) // loads 100% of a core for 4-5 seconds on a typical iMac
  println(x)
  x * 2
}
// hit Ctrl+D
compute: (x: Int)Int

scala> def foo = (0 to 20).toList.par.map(compute)
foo: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int]

scala> foo
```

Then see what happens. At the start, all cores are at 100% and as you progress in, you can clearly see that each process has its own core assigned before it even started. It won't change cores even if another core is currently free. Towards the end, it's not rare (depending on initial assignment) to have only one or two cores processing all the remaining jobs in queue, while 3 or more other cores sit idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way is to use Futures:

```
val tasks = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l")
val resultFutures: List[Future[Something]] = tasks.map(t => Future {
  someComputation(t)
}(ExecutionContext.Implicits.global))

// wait for result somehow
resultFutures.foreach(f => Await.result(f))
```

You can also take a look at the `ForkJoinTask` API.

Answer (score 1):

For `par` it's default using the [defaultTaskSupport](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/package.scala#L38), that's implemented by `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

and this `ExecutionContextExecutor` default implemented by [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), it's a **work-stealing** thread pool, the idle thread will steal the `FutureTasks` from busy threads,  so it should use the **OS** all processors.

and for your example, I think you can try to overwrite `tasksupport` to verify and try to not use **repl** to test this(maybe this is a repl bug :) ). like:

```
  val par: ParSeq[Int] = (0 to 20).toList.par
  //par.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(1)) // test run with one processor
  //default it will use all processors of OS
  par.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool())
  par.map(compute)
```